# Constants in CSV Format

Tags: openmodelica

I'm curious, does anybody know if it is possible to get OpenModelica to store parameters, constants and/or variables that have been inferred to be constant in the "CSV" format?

I understand why they aren't in there by default (space), but it would be nice to explicitly request (all of) them.  It is particularly unintuitive when variables that are not marked with the `parameter` or `constant` qualifiers are left out simply because, in a particular circumstance, the compiler has surmised that they are constants.

I couldn't find a 'simflag' that seemed to trigger writing them out.  But I'm hoping I missed something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the code and is not currently possible. I added a ticket about it.
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2876
Is a bit of a waste of space in the .csv to write them but would it be ok
to have them in a separate file, say Model_parameters.csv?